# how to fetch stock summary by item Name using Sql query from tally

Tags: php, tally

Below have XML code for Fetch Data from Tally.

```
<ENVELOPE>
   <HEADER>
      <TALLYREQUEST>ExportData</TALLYREQUEST>
   </HEADER>
   <BODY>
      <EXPORTDATA>
         <REQUESTDESC>
            <REPORTNAME>StockSummary</REPORTNAME>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
               <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Company-2</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
               <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:HTML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                 <EXPLODEFLAG>YES</EXPLODEFLAG>
                <ISITEMWISE>YES</ISITEMWISE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
         </REQUESTDESC>
      </EXPORTDATA>
   </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

1. How to write SQL QUERY in above code. for fetch data from tally.
2. Using above code I fetch all StockSummary but I need only one item.
3. Where do I write sql query in xml.

Comment: Are you asking how you can use SQL to extract specific data from XML?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question.

Comment: FabianGillenius>>No, I try how to write SQL Query in Tally.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the sql query via this XML snippet. You would need to go into the Tally code, search for this report([Report:StockSummary]), and then find the collection within this report. Once you know the collection, you will be able to pick out individual fields from the collection using the following query:

```
select $Field1, $Field2 from Collection_Name
```

Hope this helps.